# There is a django option for moodle?

Tags: php, django, moodle

There is a platform like moodle made in django or some kind of interface django/moodle?

Comment: Why should we know what moodle is?

Comment: Sorry, moodle is  a "Modular Object-Oriented Dynamic Learning Environment is a free and open-source e-learning software platform, also known as a Course Management System, Learning Management System, or Virtual Learning Environment."

Comment: @diegueus9 Did you find out anything ?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasarI I didn't find anything in 2010, but today I found: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/lms/, apparently open edx is the most active project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot think of any and Google apparently thinks the same.

[This guy](http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=56831) asked the question on the Moodle forums in 2006 (link requires login) but he received no answer, yet :)

Recently, a bug in Moodle has been fixed [allowing authentication from a Django DB](http://bugs.moodle.org/browse/MDL-18182).

Sorry I cannot help more.

Comment: You can "login" in the moodle forums as guest, no need to create an account (just making note).

Answer (score 1):

Platform like moodle, made in django. Yes there are few of those; like Django-lms (hosted on google code, it uses non relational database which may end up having huge advantage over moodle). 
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135325/lms-in-python-django-ruby-rails-php) is great discussion happening on the topic.