# LMS in Python/Django/Ruby/Rails/PHP

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, django

I am looking for an alternative to `Moodle`.
I searched and found `pinax-lms-demo`, which was Django-based;
and `Astra` which was Rails-based, but both were empty repo...

I need a LMS which has the following functions:

1. create class
2. Assign faculty
3. Upload materials
4. Take quiz
5. forum
6. scorm
7. chat

I spent more than a month using Moodle and being a developer I felt I should not use it...

Comment: > I spent more than a month using Moodle and being a developer I felt I should not use it... Any particular reason for this? I am a developer and I have used Moodle a lot in the past when coming into contact with Educational Establishments - Moodle is pretty powerful with Plugins and Modules along with some CSS theming.

Comment: Moodle has no  framework,no mvc concept .Code is very difficult to manage. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://demo.ilias.de/ Check out this lms.

Answer (score 9):

Canvas LMS https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms

Comment: We had a look at canvas and I think it looks really well done.  It's probably not something that we will end up using as it aligns tightly to a very structured learning approach.  Still leaning towards Moodle at the moment given how flexibly it can be used in different learning contexts...

Answer (score 2):

Moodle seems the only more or less usable open source LMS out there, although it's far from well written IMO. There are good payed LMS like Canvas. I don't think what you are looking for exists at this moment!

Answer (score 2):

This is a real problem as open-source LMS are all in PHP, with the exception of Sakai which is in Java.

As I've written a LMS which tries to be compatible with SCORM I can say that it's not a small work to create a SCORM implementation.

The only project in Python I know is Cloud Course, created by Google on GAE (http://code.google.com/p/cloudcourse/)

You can also use Rustici's SCORM Cloud with Python (https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/SCORMCloud_PythonLibrary)

Comment: Cloud Course is not an LMS (yet). It only allows scheduling activities at the moment and doesn't have the features like lessons, quizzes, etc which all standard LMS should have.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Canvas-LMS by Instructure

Open Sourced Code with paid SaaS option: https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki

As of June 15th: "adopted by 189 institutions (including names like Brown University, Auburn University and Wharton School of Business) and about 2.7 million users" from http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/15/cisco-teams-up-with-instructure-to-move-the-worlds-largest-it-classroom-to-the-cloud/

I managed a Moodle project and we continually wrestled with any coding changes and overall found some of the UX counter intuitive.